# Is there any way of finding the index of an embed field in discord? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
I need to find the index of an embed field in discord. Suppose I have
embed=discord.Embed(title="Embed",description="Example embed")
embed.add_field(name="one", value="1")
embed.add_field(name="two", value="2").... etc
```

and supposed I need to update a field using `embed.set_field_at(index, name, value)` so how can I get the index of the supposed field? Can I find that using its name/value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `next` to find the first match of a predicate using generator-builder notation. To get the index, you can enumerate the fields and take the index part of the enumeration.

```
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.add_field(name="test 1", value="test a")
embed.add_field(name="test 2", value="test b")

# get index of the field with name "test 2" and value "test b"
field_index = next(
    index
    for (index, f) in enumerate(embed.fields)
    if f.name == "test 2" and f.value == "test b"
)

# update field at index
embed.set_field_at(field_index, name="new name", value="new value", inline=False)
```

Comment: `await self.callback(self.cog, ctx, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: coroutine raised StopIteration` I get this error... got no idea how to fix it

Comment: That means there was no matching field, you can use try-except around the line to handle that case